# migration to pgsql, error in a function with select into

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-migration

i am migrate from sql-server to pgsql.
i use a script created in java for do that but when i try to convert this procedure(sql-server) to a function and testing in the bd(pgsql) the console show error in the part #paso1.

this is the code in sql-server:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[paBalanceClasificado]    Script Date: 30/11/2017 16:38:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[paBalanceClasificado]
@empresa int,
@fecha1 smalldatetime,
@fecha2 smalldatetime

AS

SELECT     SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1, 1) + '000000' AS Codigo, SUM(a.montoDebe) AS Debe, SUM(a.montoHaber) AS Haber
INTO #PASO1
FROM         movimientosContables a INNER JOIN
                      CuentasContables b ON a.codigoCorto = b.codigoCorto AND b.codigoEmpresa = @empresa
WHERE     (a.codigoEmpresa = @empresa and fechaProceso between @fecha1 and @fecha2)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1, 1) + '000000'
UNION ALL
SELECT     SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1, 2) + '00000' AS Codigo, SUM(a.montoDebe) AS Debe, SUM(a.montoHaber) AS Haber
FROM         movimientosContables a INNER JOIN
                      CuentasContables b ON a.codigoCorto = b.codigoCorto AND b.codigoEmpresa = @empresa
WHERE     (a.codigoEmpresa = @empresa and fechaProceso between @fecha1 and @fecha2)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1, 2) + '00000'
UNION ALL
SELECT     SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1, 4) + '000' AS Codigo, SUM(a.montoDebe) AS Debe, SUM(a.montoHaber) AS Haber
FROM         movimientosContables a INNER JOIN
                      CuentasContables b ON a.codigoCorto = b.codigoCorto AND b.codigoEmpresa = @empresa
WHERE     (a.codigoEmpresa = @empresa and fechaProceso between @fecha1 and @fecha2)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1, 4) + '000'
UNION ALL
SELECT     SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1, 7) AS Codigo, SUM(a.montoDebe) AS Debe, SUM(a.montoHaber) AS Haber
FROM         movimientosContables a INNER JOIN
                      CuentasContables b ON a.codigoCorto = b.codigoCorto AND b.codigoEmpresa = @empresa
WHERE     (a.codigoEmpresa = @empresa and fechaProceso between @fecha1 and @fecha2)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(b.codigoCuenta, 1,7)
ORDER BY codigo

SELECT     codigo, nombreCuenta, debe, haber,codigocorto
FROM         #Paso1, cuentascontables
WHERE     codigocuenta = codigo AND codigoempresa = @empresa --and 
SUBSTRING(codigoCuenta, 5,3)='000'
order by codigo
GO
```

and this is the code generated for pgsql(the error is in the variable # paso1 but i dont know if after that line exists more errors.):

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION pabalanceclasificado(
p_empresa int , 
p_fecha1 timestamp(0) , 
p_fecha2 timestamp(0) 
)
     RETURNS VOID
 AS $$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
            select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 1) + '000000' as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
        into #paso1
        from         movimientoscontables a inner join
                              cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
        where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
        group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 1) + '000000'
        union all
        select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 2) + '00000' as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
        from         movimientoscontables a inner join
                              cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
        where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
        group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 2) + '00000'
        union all
        select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 4) + '000' as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
        from         movimientoscontables a inner join
                              cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
        where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
        group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 4) + '000'
        union all
        select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 7) as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
        from         movimientoscontables a inner join
                              cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
        where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
        group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1,7)
        order by codigo
        select     codigo, nombrecuenta, debe, haber,codigocorto
        from         #paso1, cuentascontables
        where     codigocuenta = codigo and codigoempresa = p_empresa --and substring(codigocuenta, 5,3)='000'
        order by codigo
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the console shows:

```
ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de Â«#Â»
LÍNEA 11:   into #paso1
> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

But i think this is not important because i know that this is not the way to do that funtion... and i dont know how do corectly

Comment: What is the error message?  I'm not able to find it in your question.

Comment: the console shows: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de Â«#Â»
LÍNEA 11:   into #paso1
> Terminated with exit code 0.

BUT i think this is not important because i know that this is not the way to do that funtion... and i dont know how do corectly

Comment: I think the first problem with 'into #paso1'   is that  pgsql  doesn't use the '#' delimiter for a variable.  Try to change that to  just  'paso1' in all the locations.  Looking it over, it still looks  MS SQL centric..  could be all sorts of issues in there but I'd start with changing that variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in that function:

1. [String concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) is done using `||` in SQL. So `substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 1) + '000000'` should be `substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 1) || '000000'`
2. [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) are not allowed to start with `#`. So `#paso1` is an illegal variable name
3. You didn't [declare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) the variable `#paso1`.
4. You can [not store](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) multiple rows in a single variable, so it looks like you want to return the result of the query in your procedure.
5. To [return a result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE) you need to declare the function as `returns table` not `returns void`
6. To return a result set from a PL/pgSQL function you would need to use [`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING). You can't just write a select statement and don't do anything with the result.

But you don't need PL/pgSQL to return the result of a query. A SQL function is enough.

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE FUNCTION pabalanceclasificado(p_empresa int, p_fecha1 timestamp(0), p_fecha2 timestamp(0))
     RETURNS table (codigo varchar, debe bigint, bigint haber)
 AS $$
  select codigo, nombrecuenta, debe, haber,codigocorto
  from (
      select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 1) || '000000' as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
      from  movimientoscontables a 
         inner join cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
      where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
      group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 1) || '000000'

      union all

      select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 2) || '00000' as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
      from         movimientoscontables a inner join
                            cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
      where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
      group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 2) || '00000'

      union all

      select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 4) || '000' as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
      from  movimientoscontables a 
         inner join cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
      where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
      group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 4) || '000'

      union all
      select     substring(b.codigocuenta, 1, 7) as codigo, sum(a.montodebe) as debe, sum(a.montohaber) as haber
      from         movimientoscontables a 
         inner join cuentascontables b on a.codigocorto = b.codigocorto and b.codigoempresa = p_empresa
      where     (a.codigoempresa = p_empresa and fechaproceso between p_fecha1 and p_fecha2)
      group by substring(b.codigocuenta, 1,7)
   ) t
     join cuentascontables 
       on codigocuenta = codigo 
      and codigoempresa = p_empresa --and substring(codigocuenta, 5,3)='000'
   order by codigo;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

To use that function you would use:

```
select *
from pabalanceclasificado(42, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

Comment: i run your code in pgsql 9.6 and the console show:
test.sql:41: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de Â«selectÂ»
LÍNEA 35:    select  codigo, nombrecuenta, debe, haber,codigocorto;
            ^
terminated with exit code 0.

Comment: @JoséZuñiga: sorry, too much copy & paste from your code. See my edit